# this is not a boarding card go to check-in for visa check and boarding card

Tags: ryanair

I just bought a Ryanair plane ticket except that I did not see the QR code on the boarding pass, is that normal?
the message is "[image: this is not a boarding card go to check-in for visa check and boarding card]".
thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was merged and the wrong one was still open.